# Is "No la hacemos" a proper translation to "We are not doing it"? Should it be "no lo hacemos"?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, clíticos

I'm doing Duolingo Spanish. The other day, I had the sentence

> We are not doing it

To which I gave the answer

> No la hacemos

This was marked wrong, with the correct solution of

> No lo hacemos

I admit I'm not real clear on the lo, le, la difference (which Duolingo never explains), even after looking at a couple explanations online.

So, is la incorrect here (and why?), or is Duolingo (for rejecting it; they usually take most reasonable translations)?

[image: lo vs la]

Comment: Your translation was actually wrong because you don't know the gender of the object, and as @guifa said, you should **use "la" ONLY when you have the certainty that the word is female**.

Comment: But, in certain contexts (not in the given) could be ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*La* could work, if what you're doing is something feminine (like *la tarea*).

*Lo* is used when what you're doing is masculine (like *el trabajo*).

If what you're doing has no gender because it's a verb or can't be reduced to some noun (like *ir de compras*) you use the other *lo*. It's neuter, even though it looks identical.

In this case,  the neuter *lo* is the best/most common use, but masculine *lo* or feminine *la* are both perfectly grammatical acceptable.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the distinction between masculine and neuter. great answer overall, very concise.

Comment: Guifa's answer is perfect, but I'd prefer to translate it to *No lo estamos haciendo*.

Answer (score 0):

> We are not doing it.

To answer the question we have to understand the real meaning rather that just look word by word. I see it as a bunch of people and the speaker resisting to do something.

> No lo hacemos. No la hacemos.

This means "We don't do that". Which is not quite the same message you want in the original sentence.*lo/la has been explained by @guifa*

> No lo haremos. No la haremos.

This means "We won't do that" or "We are not doing it." Which is the closer meaning I get to the original sentence. //I know "haremos" implies future it is the closest to the original meaning

-Spanish native.

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't advise you to use Duolingo too long because these translation oriented exercises.

My advise would be to try out [SharedTalk](http://sharedtalk.com) so you can chat with natives text and voice and understand something as alive and flexible as a language.

**"No la hacemos"** also means **"We are not gonna make it"** (i.e. it is 4.55pm and we have to buy and finish dinner by 5pm) //Peruvian idiomatic expression, not sure if valid elsewhere though.